# Creating a dataframe with MultiIndex columns from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Using the following dictionary:

```
dic = {'S1':["2013-11-12", "2013-11-13"],
       'S2':["2013-11-15", "2013-11-17"]}
```

How can I create the following DataFrame with multiple column indices?

```
             S1                             S2                      
    Start          Stop            Start          Stop     
 2013-11-12     2013-11-13      2013-11-15     2013-11-17
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nice, simple use-case to illustrate.  Perfect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['S1', 'S2'], ['Start', 'Stop']])
print pd.DataFrame([pd.DataFrame(dic).unstack().values], columns=index)
```

Output:

```
           S1                      S2            
        Start        Stop       Start        Stop
0  2013-11-12  2013-11-13  2013-11-15  2013-11-17
```

Comment: Could you please explain the purpose of using [ ...unstack().values ] as the data from which to construct the data frame?